# how to change the color of today which is pre selected date mat-datepicker Angular

Tags: angular, datepicker, mat-datepicker, materialdatepicker

How to change the color of preselected today button in mat-datepicker

[image: here is the datepicker image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
.mat-calendar-body-selected {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #ffff00; 
}
```

Comment: not working it is working for what I have selected manually, but i need a solution for preselected date